# Change selected value from a DropDownList of Razor with JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I would like to modify the selected value of my dropdownlist without have to click on my dropdownlist.

I already tried this line with JQuery:

```
$('#select-nb-Persons-button').children(":first").text("3");
```

It printed well "3" for the dropdownlist but after, when I clicked on the dropdownlist, I noticed that it is always the first option tag that is selected and not the third option tag as I want. :

Code created by razor for the dropdownlist :

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div id="select-nb-Persons-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <span>1</span>
        <select data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ nbPersons doit être un nombre." data-val-required="Le champ nbPersons est requis." id="select-nb-Persons" name="nbPersons">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `val()` to set the selected item in a `select`. To select the item with a `value` of `3`, try this:

```
$('#select-nb-Persons').val('3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$('#select-nb-Persons-button').children('select').val('5');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zb44w8o6/)** here